# Fatal error: Call to undefined function register_rest_route()

Tags: rest-api

I get the error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function register_rest_route()` when I try to go to example.com/wp-json. What is wrong?

This is how my code looks like:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'route', '/path', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'function',
  ) );
} );
```

Comment: are you registering this route in a plugin or in your functions.php file?

Comment: I'm registering it in the functions.php file

Comment: What version of WordPress are you running?

Answer (score -1):

```
//The Following registers an api route with multiple parameters. 

 <?php
   add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'add_custom_users_api');

    function add_custom_users_api()
    {
        register_rest_route( 'route', array(
                                    'methods' => 'GET',
                                    'callback' => 'function',
                           ));
    }
```

Comment: Sweet, this seems to helped me! I had an error, which was due to wp_debug.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain the problem or how this code block solves it. How do we know what the above code does that fixes the problem?

Comment: It removed my issue at least. It doesn't make sense that it should, but for some reason I don't get an error now.